# Default Schema no MySQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Segui a instalação indicada no [site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/) do MySQL. Após isso, instalei o Workbench também seguindo o comando indicado no site oficial.

Na faculdade uso Windows nos labs e lá já vem com uns schemas padrão como o Sakila.

Em casa uso o Ubuntu 18.04 para fazer trabalhos e, ao instalar o MySQL, não vieram essas schemas.

O trabalho passado na matéria de Banco de Dados é pra ser feito justamente no Sakila e não aparece aqui.

Gostaria de saber se existe um comando para que seja feita a criação deles ou se coloquei algo errado durante a instalação.

`Obs.: pelo menos lá na faculdade, esses schemas já vêm populados, por isso foi passado trabalho para manipulação do Sakila.`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: Talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260235/importing-data-and-schema-to-mysql-workbench